# Constructor in a lib project unjustly accused of not having the right number of arguments

Tags: c#

This is the constructor:

```
namespace CDALog
{
    class ErrorMessage : Message
    {
        public ErrorMessage(string application, string subject, string code)
        {
            this.Application = application;
            this.Subject = subject;
            this.Code = code;
            this.MessageType = "ERROR";
        }
```

when I try to create an instance in the main project, like this:

```
CDALog.ErrorMessage m = new CDALog.ErrorMessage(Logger.Application, "RunJob", "Main");
```

I get this error message:

> Error  17  'CDALog.ErrorMessage' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Not quite sure what to make of it, there is only one constructor and it has exactly 3 arguments. I've tried Clean and Rebuild, it didn't help.

EDIT:
I also noticed that other public members are "inaccessible due to protection level" and IntelliType isn't displaying any members.

Comment: Is it possible you have an old version of the library registered in GAC? GAC is the first place where references are looked for, it comes even before other project references

Comment: I haven't put this in the GAC yet, it is still a project in the same solution.

Comment: Is `Logger.Application` a String?

Comment: Yes, Logger.Application is a string.

Comment: Is the problem that the class isn't public?

Comment: The code presented here doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint here is that everything is "inaccessible due to protection level". The class does not have an access modifier applied to it, which means that it is `internal`.

`internal` classes can not be accessed outside their assembly, so you can't use that constructor (or anything else). Simply put `public` before the class declaration to solve the issue.